# Umbraco 5 implementing Ajax by adding new MVC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, umbraco

I am trying to implement AJax on Umbraco 5(jupiter), i have tried to create Surface controllers, which works great with normal post back but it do not provide the facility to use Mvc Ajax Controls i-e Ajax.BeginForm Etc..., I have now added a new MVC Area in the Application, i am able to send Post Back through Ajax form easily to the Controller's Action but i WHAT should i return from this Action, As CurrentUmbracoPage is not accessible(because it is not a Surface Controller), my code is fairly simple,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("HandleFollowsUs", "propertyDetails", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader", UpdateTargetId = "fuError" }))
{
 <input type="image" style="border-width: 0px;" src="/images/btnSubmitN.jpg"  id="btn_submitEmail" /></span>

}
AND my ACTION is 
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleFollowsUs(FormCollection collection) {
//Do Something
Return View();//////This is where i am confused.
}
```

If i return View, it is not in the New area, partial View will only return a bit portion of the Page, :/
Any Help would be appreciated,
Thanks,
Sher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jquery Ajax instead and return a string, it wont effect the normal routing of Umbraco 5. Sample Code is as below

```
function loadList(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/en/propertydetails/searchListView",
    data: "loc=" + loc + "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&bedrooms=" + bedrooms + "&adults=" + adults + "&children=" + children + "&offerCode=" + offerCode,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        //alert('error');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //do something with response
        populateSearchList(response);
    }
});
```

}

And my Action is

```
[HttpPost]
    public string searchListView(string loc, string endDate, string startDate, string bedrooms, string adults, string children, string offerCode)
    {
//Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could if course send the current URL as a hidden form files so that HandleFollowUs can do the redirect.

But if I understand correctly you just want to do some client side validation? Consider using the unobtrusive validation framework already present in the MVC framework. Have a look at this post for more information: [ASP.NET MVC 3 - Ajax.BeginForm vs jQuery Form Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911834/asp-net-mvc-3-ajax-beginform-vs-jquery-form-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the reply sebastiaan, i dont want to do a client side validation, i want user to submit his email so he can follow our newsletter, 
actually i am doing all this because of your package (jupiter as Visual studio application), and it is working great THANKS a million, also i have solved the problem by using Jquery ajax.

Comment: You're welcome. Was going to suggest plain jQuery but I see you already fixed it that way, well done!